# Is there a way to offset a view from center?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, center, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to possition my button not exactly in center, but let's say in the 2/5s of the screen height, I was looking for attribute unsuccessfully, so I tried this approach

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="20dp" >

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fakeView"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/flashlight_button_description"
    android:src="@drawable/freeml_bright" />

   <View
    android:id="@+id/fakeView"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#FFAABB" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However it does not work, even if I set margin on the fake view.

Padding attribute works, however as it is a big image and if I want it to start at 2/5ths of screen height, it covers the center point of screen, so if I use padding attribute it works but it pushes it away from center and does not allow it to cover it.

Alhough, I made it work using `LinearLayout`, which I wanted to avoid because there are more Views on top and bottom next to each other so it would lead to nested views using linear layout. Unfortunately I think its the only option.

It basically it uses another linear layout that fills the remaining space left unused by top and bottom views with `height=0dp` and `weight=1` and sets its gravity to center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/application_logo_description"
        android:src="@drawable/mylight" />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/settings_button_description"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_button" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flashlight_button_description"
        android:src="@drawable/flashlight_button_selector" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="#FFAABB" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@string/powered_by_description"
    android:src="@drawable/powered_by" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ad_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ad_button_description"
    android:src="@drawable/freeml" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 33):

Depending on the screen size of the target device, padding by X dp might move it more than just a fifth of the height.

You might have to code this movement yourself. However, nothing prevents you from doing:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 android:padding="20dp" >

<View
android:id="@+id/fakeView"
android:layout_width="10dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#FFAABB" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/fakeView"
android:marginBottom="50dp"
android:background="@null"
android:contentDescription="@string/flashlight_button_description"
android:src="@drawable/freeml_bright" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A fake view in the middle!  That's thinking outside the box, just what I needed! :)

Answer (score 6):

Don't use margin, use padding (top), like so:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/fakeView"
android:layout_width="10dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:paddingTop="80dp"
android:background="#FFAABB" />
```

That should work, though I've not tested it!

Comment: Hi, it works, however as i might have mislead you, beacause its a fairly big image in the imagebutton, so if i want to have it start in 2/5s of the screen height, therefore it covers the center point of screen. IF i use your suggested answer it pushes the button away from the center and does not allow it to cover it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try replacing paddingTop with paddingBottom?

Comment: Oh i actually read it wrong, setting padding on the centered fake view doesnt work at all. Setting padding on the button above it just pushes  the button upwards which is not the solution for me as i want it to cover the mid point

Answer (score 3):

try using attribute android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fakeView"