# How to align Button by center and make offset

Tags: android, layout, android-view, android-button

I would like to align button on center and make offset i was tried approach like that [Is there a way to offset a view from center in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690274/is-there-a-way-to-offset-a-view-from-center-in-android) but it do not work. For example:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/fakeView"
android:layout_width="10dp"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:paddingTop="80dp"
android:background="#FFAABB" />
```

Still stay on center

Is any way accomplish like this:

[image]

UPDATE:

my full layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <ImageButton 
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Center it then use `android:layout_marginLeft=""` to move it over however far you want

Comment: @BillGary look at updated it not work still.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

one way is to use a ancher view which is centerd inside your relative layout, set your button right of it and set your margin.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

         <ImageButton 
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anchor"
             />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

or try:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"  >

         <ImageButton 
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="100dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```